# real memory vs profiled memory python

Tags: python, garbage-collection, memory-profiling

Using [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) to aid in project that is requiring freeing up some memory at various points. The development environment is OS X snow leopard.

The profiled memory, as shown below, is peaking at around `414.699 MiB`, but the Activity Monitor is showing the process peaking at nearly twice that (more than `900 MB`).

```
    Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    24   20.441 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
    25                             def do_work():
    26                                 "Call each function in order"
    27   20.445 MiB    0.004 MiB       x = audio.AudioQuantumList() 
    28  137.098 MiB  116.652 MiB       audiofile = make_objects("/Users/path/audio/Track01.mp3")
    29  295.480 MiB  158.383 MiB       audiofile2 = make_objects("/Users/path/audio/Track02.mp3")
    30  414.699 MiB  119.219 MiB       audiofile3 = make_objects("/Users/path/audio/Track03.mp3")
    31  414.699 MiB    0.000 MiB       x = add_to_list(audiofile, x)
    32  417.426 MiB    2.727 MiB       audiofile = clear_memory(audiofile)  
    33  417.426 MiB    0.000 MiB       gc.collect()
    34  417.426 MiB    0.000 MiB       x = add_to_list(audiofile2, x)
    35  425.047 MiB    7.621 MiB       audiofile2 = clear_memory(audiofile2)  
    36  285.344 MiB -139.703 MiB       gc.collect()
    37  285.344 MiB    0.000 MiB       x = add_to_list(audiofile3, x)
    38  340.082 MiB   54.738 MiB       audiofile3 = clear_memory(audiofile3)  
    39  339.582 MiB   -0.500 MiB       gc.collect()
```

Is it normal for memory_profiler to show half of the memory that's actually being used by the CPU(s)? And is that in fact what is occurring here?

Also note that when `gc.collect` is not explicitly called, the `-139.703 MiB` freed at line `36` become:

```
================================================
35  374.895 MiB  -45.617 MiB       audiofile2 = clear_memory(audiofile2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line-by-line report, `memory_profiler` measures the memory usage after the execution of each line. In the memory peaks inside a function, e.g inside `make_objects` but the memory is released before the function returns, then memory_profiler will not report that usage.

Workarounds include decorating also the nested functions (e.g. make_objects) or using mprof (distributed with memory_profiler) to report memory usage as a function of time.